# Spring application deployed but context fails to start

Tags: xml, spring, spring-mvc, web.xml, tomcat8

After some modifications in my XML configuration files, my current spring project do not start anymore on tomcat. Message displayed is:

```
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /loja but context failed to start
```

in the **catalina.out** file, it's displayed this error message:

```
GRAVE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
fev 10, 2017 8:56:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
GRAVE: Context [/loja] startup failed due to previous errors
fev 10, 2017 8:56:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFORMAÇÕES: Deployment of web application archive /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/loja.war has finished in 1,045 ms
```

my configurations files are:

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>loja</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/rootContext.xml,/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springmvcapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-name>
            <param-value>param-value</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**rootContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:mydata"/>
        <property name="username" value="kleber"/>
        <property name="password" value="123"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.kleber.model" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.kleber"></context:component-scan>

    <context:annotation-config/>

    <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" jsr250-annotations="disabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

    <bean id="templateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ServletContextTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.html</value>
        </property>
        <property name="templateMode">
            <value>HTML5</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="templateEngine"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolver" ref="templateResolver"></property>
        <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.kleber.thymeleaf.dialect.Field"/>
                <bean class="org.kleber.thymeleaf.dialect.Form"/>
                <bean class="org.kleber.thymeleaf.dialect.Util"/>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"></property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <mvc:resources location="/css/" mapping="/css/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/img/" mapping="/img/**" />
    <mvc:resources location="/js/" mapping="/js/**" />
</beans>
```

**securityContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">  
    <security:http pattern="/" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/css/**" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/img/**" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http pattern="/js/**" security="none"></security:http>

    <security:http>
        <security:form-login login-page="/signin" login-processing-url="/login" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" delete-cookies='JSESSIONID' />
        <security:remember-me key="remember-me" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"></security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"></bean>
</beans>
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here?

Comment: From log attached: `GRAVE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`
Please post some details.

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak Do you know what's the appropriate container log file? I look the others log files in the same directory of catalina.out but don't find any relevant information about this error.

Comment: Have you tried changing the log level to DEBUG?

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak i am not using log4j here.

Comment: @PiotrSołtysiak and even after configure the log4j, the message remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue fixing this declaration:

```
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
```

The value which works was that:

```
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
```